# How to count ocurrences in a column dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
        ORF    IDClass  genName                               ORFDesc
0      b186  [1,1,1,0]   'bglS'                      beta-glucosidase
1     b2202  [1,1,1,0]   'cbhK'                   carbohydrate kinase
2      b727  [1,1,1,0]   'fucA'         L-fuculose phosphate aldolase
3     b1731  [1,1,1,0]  'gabD1'  succinate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase
4      b234  [1,1,1,0]  'gabD2'  succinate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase
```

and I need to count how many registers have IDClass = [1,1,1,0],  IDClass = [1,2,0,0] etc

Im using he str.count().sum() function but it returns me more ocurrences than registers in my dataset. What am I doing wrong?

Ex:

```
IN: count = df2.IDClass.str.count('[1,1,1,0]').sum()
OUT: [3924 rows x 4 columns]
     21552
```

If I do:

```
IN: count = df2.IDClass.str.count('[1,1,1,0]').sum()
OUT: [3924 rows x 4 columns]
0       7
1       7
2       7
3       7
4       7
       ..
3919    6
3920    6
3921    6
3922    6
3923    6
```

Any idea?
Thanks is advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `IDClass` is string type, you can just do:

```
df['IDClass'].value_counts()
```

If that gives an error, it's likely that your `IDClass` is list type. Then you can use `tuple`:

```
df['IDClass'].apply(tuple).value_counts()
```